# act_as_followers get all posts of user I'm following

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, acts-as-follower

Im trying to get all the `Posts` from the the `Users`. I'm following using the [act_as_follower](https://github.com/tcocca/acts_as_follower) gem. The User follows a `profile` model, and `Posts` belong to a `User`.

My User model:

```
  acts_as_follower
```

My Profile model the user follows:

```
  belongs_to :user
  acts_as_followable
```

Post model:

```
  belongs_to :user
```

My Post Controller.rb:

```
  def follow
    @profile = Profile.find(params[:id])
    current_user.follow(@profile)
    redirect_to :back
  end

  def unfollow
    @profile = Profile.find(params[:id])
    current_user.stop_following(@profile)
    redirect_to :back
  end
```

Im trying to implement something like this using `follows_by_type` method provided:

```
@posts = current_user.follows_by_type('Post').order("created_at DESC")
```

But the thing is the User follows the Profile model, but here I'm looking for a type 'Post'.

**EDIT**

In my index controller i'v set up the following:

```
@favoritePost = Post.where(user_id: current_user.all_follows.pluck(:id))
```

And in the view iv implemented this:

```
<% if user_signed_in? %>
   <%@favoritePost.each do |post| %>
      <%= post.title %>
   <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I worked out this solution, might not be the best, but it works as required.**

In my controller i set this up:

```
@following = current_user.all_following
@followposts = @following.each do |f|
  f.user.id
end
```

And in my view I have set this up:

```
<% @followposts.each do |f| %>
  <% f.user.posts.each do |g| %>
    <%= g.title %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 2):

The gem lets you follow multiple models and `follows_by_type('Post')` filters the Posts you follow.

What you're looking to do is to return the posts from the users you follow.

Controller

```
@posts = Post.where(user_id: current_user.all_following.pluck(:id))
```

View

```
<% @posts.each do |post| %>
  <%= post.title %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Would i need to add `acts_as_followable` to my Post model?

Comment: @GurmukhSingh you don't need to because you're not following the post, just the user.

Comment: I'm getting undefined method `all_follows' for nil:NilClass

Comment: @GurmukhSingh so you don't have `current_user` Are you signed in?

Comment: @GurmukhSingh you should also put the check for signed in user in your controller `@favoritePost = Post.where(user_id: current_user.all_follows.pluck(:id)) if current_user`

Comment: @hussainAhmed, i tried this solution but i get a `cant load polymorphic relation error`, Iv worked out a solution, is it ok to leave this logic in the controller or shift it to the model? if so how could i shift it to the model?